# Searching multiple tags with regex

Tags: vim, neovim

I am trying to search for multiple tags with regex.
Something like this:

```
:tag /blabla\|user
```

I would like to search tags for blabla and user but for some reason it is not working. I tried all the combination I can think of, with and without magic flag. The help file said it accepts regex so I think it should be working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your original command, `:tag /blabla\|user`, is interpreted "as-is"; it needs one more forward slash to work:

```
:tag /blabla\\|user
```

Comment: thx, lost a lot of time on this one... when i map it to key i need to insert another backslash so in the end this is what I was looking for:  map somekey :tag /blabla\\\|user